# Why does my LED bulb flicker in freezing temps?

Tags: light-fixture, led

I installed an LED bulb in a fixture in my barn. It replaced a halogen. Works fine, except in freezing temps. It'll flicker incessantly and if it's really cold it doesn't even go on. I thought LEDs work great in freezing temps. I have many other LEDs in my barn that have no problem. What the heck?

Comment: Usually if you have a number of the same bulbs and one does not work right, that one is defective.

Comment: Hmm. Makes sense. I will get an EXPENSIVE new bulb and will have to wait till next winter to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Usually expensive does not equal no defects.  Years ago I received a CFL bulb from the power company, which should of had no defects.  It blew as soon as I turned it on, another bulb on sale in the same fixture as been working ever since.

Comment: Is it an outdoor rated bulb?

Comment: The manufacturer should have specified an _operating temperature range_, e.g. "-20°C (-4°F) to a maximum of +60°C (+140°F)". If you are using the lamp within that range and it doesn't work properly then you have a warranty claim. If outside the range then you have misused the lamp. If the manufacturer can't be bothered to specify operating conditions then you have chosen poorly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bunch of LED lights in my garage from Harbor Freight. Several of them buzz and flicker for a few minutes when I first turn them on, especially if it's cold. Most do not, though.

I mention that they're from HF because they're known for producing lower quality products (though these have been, otherwise, great fixtures). It may be an issue with the particular bulb you've installed. If you bought a package with several, you may want to try a different bulb from the package - there could be issues with the specific one you grabbed and this specific bulb might do just fine in a warmer locale.  It could simply be the brand you purchased isn't all that great in the cold.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a defective bulb. ( Maybe the term should be "sensitive".)
I had the same issue with an outside light. Bulb flickered when cold. Replaced the bulb with another from the same box. Problem solved.  I used the "flicker" bulb in an indoor lamp and it worked fine.